# How do I run GEB tests using the firefox driver?

Tags: selenium, grails, testing, groovy, geb

First, where do I download the firefox driver?
How do I set Geb to run tests using this driver in a Grails application.

I'm using Grails 2.3.7, and so far, I have this:

In my GebConfig.groovy:

```
// Testing frameworks
def gebVersion = "0.9.2"
def seleniumVersion = "2.32.0"

dependencies {
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
   // test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    test "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    test "org.gebish:geb-junit4:$gebVersion"
    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.31.0"

    test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.31.0"
}
```

In GebConfig.groovy:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension

driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }

environments {
    // run as “grails -Dgeb.env=firefox test-app”
    // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver
    firefox {
        driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to upgrade the driver to a more recent version. 2.52.0 is the recent by now, so the Firefox browser has likely been updated many times since that driver was build.

I.e, change to

```
test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.52.0"

test "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.52.0"
```

And you should update the gebVersion to 0.13.0 and  seleniumVersion to 2.52.0

The driver is downloaded from the maven repo automatically, and make sure the GebConfig.groovy file is on the classpath - I usually put it in the global folder. See example in this repo: https://github.com/JacobAae/dm844-sample-project/